# How can I call this function from another method in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call `levelSystemAnimated.ExpSkip()`
It needs to be in another method since I want to use it with a button.

```
[SerializeField]
private LevelUI levelUI;

private LevelSystem levelSystem = new LevelSystem();

void Start() {
  LevelSystemAnimated levelSystemAnimated = new LevelSystemAnimated(levelSystem);

  if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.save")) {
    SaveData data = SaveSystem.LoadData();

    levelSystemAnimated.AddLoadExp(data.exp);
    levelSystemAnimated.SetLoadLevel(data.level);
    levelSystem.SetLoadLevel(data.level);
    levelSystem.AddLoadExp(data.exp);
  }
  levelSystem.AddExperience(0);

  levelUI.SetLevelSystemAnimated(levelSystemAnimated);
  levelUI.SetLevelSystem(levelSystem);

  youCrashed.SetActive(false);
  LoadPlusScore();
  YouCrashed();
  InvokeRepeating("AddPlusXP", 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

public void SkipExp() {
  levelSystemAnimated.ExpSkip();
  SkipExpButton.SetActive(false);
}
```

Here is my code, didn't achieve to do it.

Notice I'm a beginner.

Comment: So? Writr another method that calls that line? You only create it in start .. outside your local variable doesn't exist => create a field instead in your class `private LevelSystemAnimated levelSystemAnimated;` and remove `LevelSystemAnimated` from your `Start` method

Comment: @derHugo I know what you're trying to say, but `LevelSystemAnimated` is using `LevelSystem`, so if I do that I get `CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property`.

Comment: I said remove the `LevelSystemAnimated` type declaration .. i didn't mean don't initialize the field in `Start` .. you should still keep that line itself ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thank you very much, actually helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I will give to you an example with a script of the empty gameObject containing the button.

Firstly you need to access to the script, you can do it with

```
public levelSystemAnimated levelSystem;
```

And drag the gameObject of the script inside the inspector, or you can

```
void Start()
{
   GameObject levelSystem = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("levelSystemObj");
   //then you can easily access to the script with a GetComponent
}
```

In either ways, you will now have the access to the script so you can simply

```
public void ButtonToPress()
{
  levelSystem.SkipExp();
}
```

So in the button **on press** you put the function `ButtonToPress()` and when you press it it is going to start that function

Comment: Thanks for the help, but levelSystemAnimated is not a MonoBehaviour script, so it can't be added to any gameObject, thats where the problem came from.

Comment: you can access it with a public variable and a scriptable object, there are many ways, it depends on your project @Pupaak